# SSL connection successful from jUnit test but not on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, intellij-idea, junit

I have a problem with an SSL connection instantly throwing a *java.net.SocketException: Connection reset* when a method is running in a Tomcat 8 instance but not when the same method from is running in a jUnit test launched in IntelliJ IDEA.

My guess is there is a difference between the SSL contexts of those executions, but I can't figure out where.

The stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.readResponseFromConnection(HttpHelper.java:71)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.getResponse(HttpHelper.java:175)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeGetRequest(HttpHelper.java:149)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:50)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:42)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexEndpoint(MexParser.java:105)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:53)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:841)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:66)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:173)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163)
```

As you can see, we're using Microsoft adal4j Authentication library, which relies on sun SSLSocket library. So I don't have full control over the code nor on which URL this library tries to reach, but I got a successful result when issuing GET request to those URLs with a random HTTP client, so I think it's not due to the remote server.

Also, I couldn't find any obvious differences when comparing SSL related class instances when debugging the method in both contexts.

So my questions are :

- Do you guys have an idea of why this exception occurs when the code is running in Tomcat 8 but not in a jUnit test ran by IntelliJ IDEA ?
- Is there any specific Tomcat SSL related configuration I should know about ? (Edit : SSL configuration regarding ***issuing*** requests, not *receiving* them)

Many thanks !

**Edit : Here is the SSL logs showing when running the code on Tomcat 8, with the -Djavax.net.debug=all VM option :**

```
    Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 64
0000: C5 9E 29 2A 8B 63 20 6C   E0 A6 49 4E 22 84 C7 3B  ..)*.c l..IN"..;
0010: 01 00 F3 38 92 FE 6A 86   C5 8E 24 33 A2 06 CD 8C  ...8..j...$3....
0020: E5 41 AB C1 90 02 68 2E   DA 16 98 16 A0 D2 10 F9  .A....h.........
0030: E8 F8 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D   0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D  ................
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
[Raw write]: length = 69
0000: 15 03 03 00 40 3F FC 91   B2 8E 40 60 E9 53 92 F1  ....@?....@`.S..
0010: DC 30 3E 6B 17 24 24 73   28 27 A2 0D 5A 21 10 49  .0>k.$$s('..Z!.I
0020: 10 3F 2A 0C 66 43 B2 7C   9C AF 7D DD 8D 56 9A 54  .?*.fC.......V.T
0030: 5C 50 7D 02 A7 2E CD 08   09 8B 7C 01 23 73 39 A2  \P..........#s9.
0040: BE EE 25 69 C6                                     ..%i.
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeSocket(true)
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
pool-3-thread-1, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1470314350 bytes = { 213, 98, 148, 139, 96, 52, 131, 136, 198, 166, 65, 128, 70, 254, 68, 33, 73, 132, 111, 109, 16, 154, 180, 207, 22, 254, 151, 143 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 193
0000: 01 00 00 BD 03 03 58 A3   37 6E D5 62 94 8B 60 34  ......X.7n.b..`4
0010: 83 88 C6 A6 41 80 46 FE   44 21 49 84 6F 6D 10 9A  ....A.F.D!I.om..
0020: B4 CF 16 FE 97 8F 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  ........:.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
0060: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 5A 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......Z...4.2...
0070: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0080: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0090: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
00A0: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   18 00 16 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00B0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 03   03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00C0: 02                                                 .
pool-3-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 193
[Raw write]: length = 198
0000: 16 03 03 00 C1 01 00 00   BD 03 03 58 A3 37 6E D5  ...........X.7n.
0010: 62 94 8B 60 34 83 88 C6   A6 41 80 46 FE 44 21 49  b..`4....A.F.D!I
0020: 84 6F 6D 10 9A B4 CF 16   FE 97 8F 00 00 3A C0 23  .om..........:.#
0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9C  ./.....3.2.+./..
0050: C0 2D C0 31 00 9E 00 A2   C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03  .-.1............
0060: C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00 FF   01 00 00 5A 00 0A 00 34  ...........Z...4
0070: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0080: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0090: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
00A0: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00 00 0D 00 18 00 16  ................
00B0: 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01   04 03 04 01 03 03 03 01  ................
00C0: 02 03 02 01 02 02                                  ......
pool-3-thread-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
pool-3-thread-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
pool-3-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
pool-3-thread-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
pool-3-thread-1, called closeSocket()
17-02-14 17:59:26.731   ERROR c.m.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID: f603f1ee-2e0c-4ed7-a345-f963e6b7d253] Request to acquire token failed.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.readResponseFromConnection(HttpHelper.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.getResponse(HttpHelper.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeGetRequest(HttpHelper.java:149)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:50)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexEndpoint(MexParser.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:53)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:841)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:66)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:173)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is the same as the one I get from running as a jUnit test until the errors occurs. It didn't help me much but maybe someone will guess what is going on.

Comment: Does Tomcat run on the same JVM as JUnit test in the IDE?

Comment: No, they don't. They both run in their own JVM, though they share the same JDK installations.

Comment: This could be the case of the problem, try using the same JVM version for Tomcat.

Comment: I was editing my comment, you've been really quick to answer :) They share the same binaries from the same JDK installation (version 1.8.0_91). I think this is what you meant.

Comment: Try running both with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` option and see what's the difference in the debug output for SSL connection. It's also possible to get even more detailed logs using the following: `-Djava.security.debug=certpath -Djavax.net.debug=all`

Comment: I tried that yesterday, and though I'm not sure considering the complexity of SSL logs, it didn't help me finding the cause of the error. I'll do it again with both jUnit and Tomcat runtimes and post the part where the results get different.

Comment: And thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I added the trace from the faulty SSL connection to my post. Hope it helps.